# Failing to create custom button on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a button that looks like a navbar button that collapses and expands a certain div on click. I'm getting the event handling to work as it should, but the button won't turn into the look that I want it to, which is something like [this](http://centriclearning.net/images/mobile-nav-button2.png). I've used three `<span class="icon-bar"></span>` elements, but it doesn't work. Have a look at the [codepen](https://codepen.io/sahandz/pen/zRzoEP). Is the span element `icon-bar` class dated? How to achieve what I want instead?

EDIT: It's a little hard to see the button but it's there. It's empty, which is the problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row dish-item-view">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dinner Overview</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icor-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 sidebar in" id="sidebar">
         <h4>To collapse</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You've been around long enough to know you post the code in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, sorted.

Comment: Are you opposed to using something like Font Awesome for an icon in a button?

Comment: No, I guess not. Although it would be nice to know why my current solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that bootstraps styles all rely off parent elements having certain classes.

I have create this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/rmLmvekr/2/) to demonstrate how you can successfully get the hamburger menu. It's pretty simple if you use bootstraps built in styles. Just create a navbar like this:

```
<div class="navbar custom-hamburger-menu" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#customHamburgerMenuContent">
             <span class="sr-only">Screen reader title</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
    </div>

    <div id="customHamburgerMenuContent" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        Collapsible content
    </div>
</div>
```

And then all you have to do is style the `.icon-bar`s like this:

```
.custom-hamburger-menu .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{ 
    background-color: black;
}
```